# Fundamental domain for the group of transformations generated by $\tau \mapsto \tau + 2$ and $\tau \mapsto -1/\tau$

Tags: complex-analysis

Define the following fractional linear transformations (acting on elements of $\mathbb C$):

- $T_2:\tau \mapsto \tau + 2$
- $S: \tau \mapsto -1/\tau$

Let $G$ be the group of transformations generated by $T_2$ and $S$.

In my complex analysis textbook, there is a proof that for each point $\tau$ in the upper half-plane, there exists a mapping $g \in G$ such that $g(\tau) \in \mathcal F = \{\tau \in \mathbb C: |\Re(\tau)| \leq 1 \text{ and } \Im(\tau) \geq 0 \text{ and } |\tau| \geq 1 \}$.

Suppose we are given some point $\tau$. The proof begins by choosing $g \in G$ such that $\Im(g(\tau))$ is maximal. My question is, how do we know that there exists such a mapping $g$? (What if, for every $g \in G$, we can find a $g_1 \in G$ such that $\Im(g(\tau)) < \Im(g_1(\tau))$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $g=\left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}\right)$,

$$\Im(g(\tau)) = \frac{\Im \tau}{|c\tau + d|^2}.$$

The numbers $c\tau + d$ form a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$, which is discrete, and therefore $|c\tau + d|$ attains its minimum, which is a positive number. Therefore...

Comment: Thank you! I had not thought about the structure of $G$ at all.

Comment: You are most welcome, Alan!